# What is the role of Mary the Mother of God in the Temple of God?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, revelation, temple, ark-of-the-covenant

Revelation 11:19-12:1 shows that Mary is in the Temple. What is her role here? Is it similar to the Old Ark of the Covenant, or is she there interceding to her Son?

Comment: It is not clear to me that the woman clothed in the sun in Revelation 12:1 is in the temple in Revelation 11:19.  Both are in heaven but heaven is large.

Comment: Nor is it clear to me that the woman clothed in the sun is definitely Mary.  To illustrate the issue, Pope Pius X identified that woman as Mary in his encyclical *Ad diem illum laetissimum* but Pope Pius XII did not in his encyclical *Ad Caeli Reginam* when it would have been appropriate to do so.